# Limit result by user id, sort by create date

Tags: solr

I have a schema like for product table. It look like this:

id
title
user_id
create_date

When run the search query, how can I limit up to 3 product per user, and sort them by create_date.

Thank in advance

Comment: use Result Grouping features of SOLR

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Result Grouping Feature of SOLR, try below query, it will group your data as per `user_id` and get 3 product of each `user_id` by their `created_date` descending order

```
http://<ip_address>:<port>/solr/<core_name>/select?q=*:*&fl=id&group=true&group.field=user_id&group.limit=3&group.sort=create_date+desc
```

[SOLR WIKI GUIDE - RESULT GROUPING](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)